# How do I insert bold words inside math mode?

Tags: math-mode

I want to make write an equation that looks like this:

```
if (x belongs to A) then (B is a subset of C)
```

I tried using

```
\documentclass[]{minimal}
\begin{document}
\[ if x \in A then B \subseteq C \]
\end{document}
```

but it ended up looking pretty ugly, with all the words jumbled together

[image: my pdf output]

How can I make the "if"  and the "then" appear as separate, bold words to make it clearer that they are keywords? Is there a way to do that from within math mode?

Comment: `\[\textbf{if } x \in A \textbf{ then } B \subseteq C\]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please avoid mixing text and math if your message can be spelled out as you have here. The easiest way to write this is

```
If $x\in A$ then $B$ is a subset of $C$. In other words 
\( x\in A \implies B \subseteq C \)
```

But as a complete answer you can write

```
\[ \text{\textbf{If }} x \in A \text{\textbf{ then }}B \subseteq C \]
```

As a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % <-- fixes, enhances amsmath
\begin{document}
If $x\in A$ then $B$ is a subset of $C$. In other words \( x\in A \implies B \subseteq C \)
    \[ \text{\textbf{If }} x \in A \text{\textbf{ then }}B \subseteq C \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use simply `\texbf{If }` and `\textbf{ then }`?

Comment: @Bernard -- in the (unlikely) event that bold words occur in a sub/superscript or other environment in a size other than that of the surrounding text, the `\text` command will choose the appropriate size.

Comment: @barbara beeton: I didn't know that. Never tried either, I confess.